# Override the NuGet package version from CLI

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I like to use the build number or some other computed version number in my CICD pipeline for NuGet packages. Essentially, I like the developer to control the major and minor version numbers but increment the build automatically.

With the `nuget.exe` I could use the `-Version` switch to override the version in the final package. However with a .NET Core 2.0 library project this fails, and I have to use `dotnet pack`, see:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4491

The is only a `--version-prefix` CLI argument for `dotnet pack` so how do I override the version completely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the barely-documented `/p` option:

```
dotnet pack /p:PackageVersion=2.1.0
```

See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x

Obviously, you can combine this as you like in your CICD tool, like for VSTS:

```
/p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

> **Note** VSTS has a few options for automatic versioning within the .NET Core build task when "pack" is the verb (in preview as of 5th Oct 2017).

The final solution for me on VSTS was to use the .NET Core `dotnet pack` task with the `Use the build number` setting and the following as the build number format set in the Options for the build definition:

```
2.0.$(Build.BuildId)
```

The engineer will need to alter the version upon making large or breaking changes. I'd prefer this in the code; one day I'll write some script to hoist the number from the `.csproj` and into the build system.

Comment: btw you can also define `/p:BuildNumber=$(Build.BuildId)` and then in the csproj have an `<BuildNumer Condition="'$(BuildNumber)'==''">0</…>` and `<Version>2.0.$(BuildNumber)</…>` so you can set a part of the version in the csproj

Comment: I tried it and it does not seem to do anything. Nor does it throw any errors.

Comment: Thank you @MartinUllrich. That worked very well for me.